# Can `len()` be greater than `cap()` for a slice in Go?

Tags: go, slice

https://github.com/google/codesearch/blob/master/index/write.go#L498

The following code is mentioned in on the above page. Can `len()` be greater than `cap()`? I think `=` instead of `>=` should be used here. Thanks.

```
    if len(b.buf) >= cap(b.buf) {
```

Comment: The inverse of `<` is `>=`. It's common to include the entire possible range to check, `>=` as opposed to `==` in case of "off-by-one" errors (which can't really happen here, but is good practice in general). The canonical example is the condition in a for/while loop, which while intended to increment by 1 each iteration, would go into an infinite loop if the `==` condition got skipped.

Comment: @JimB Could you show an example code  when `>` can take?

Comment: @user1424739, sorry, I don’t understand what that means.

Comment: Yes. If you have a hardware defect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spec: Length and capacity:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)

> The capacity of a slice is the number of elements for which there is space allocated in the underlying array. At any time the following relationship holds:
>
> ```
> 0 <= len(s) <= cap(s)
> ```

So no, length of a slice cannot be greater than its capacity.

In the referenced code `len(b.buf) == cap(b.buf)` would be enough, it may be the code calculated length some other way (e.g. including the length of something to be appended), which would make sense. Then it could be the code was changed / rewritten but not the relation.